# Bayesian Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, economics, bayes-theorem

Very simple question: Assume we are given a Bayesian game (in any form). Do we always find all Bayesian Nash equilibria by transforming the game into Bayesian normal form?

I think so, why should it not be, but are there some exceptions to this?

Comment: You're right in principle that any game of incomplete information (which you referred to as a Bayesian game) can be represented in the Bayesian normal form, and from it all BNEs can be found. In practice, however, a Bayesian normal form may not always be feasible, or at least more useful than say the extensive form. For example, an incomplete information game with 4 players would need a 4-dimensional matrix.

Comment: @HerrK. Okay, that I understand. But what do you mean by feasible? That we can't even tackle the problem?

Comment: By feasible I just mean practical.

Comment: Ah ok, now I am relieved. Thank you